# Getting started with Firebase, iOS and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

Perhaps this is a n00b question but I'm going to ask it anyways.  I followed the instructions for adding Firebase to a Swift app via CocoaPods.  Everything seems to have worked fine.  Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FirebaseDemo2' do
    # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for FirebaseDemo2
    pod 'Firebase'
end
```

When trying to import the Firebase module into the AppDelegate, at first Xcode complains it cannot find it but the project builds just fine.  However, when trying to add the `FIRApp` it then fails to build because it cannot find the class.

The Podfile is in the same directory as the .xcodeproj and I am opening the .xcworkspace file in Xcode.  This is really confusing me.  Can someone see what I am doing wrong?  Is CocoaPods misconfigured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, it installed 2.5.1 but you need 3.2.0

Try running

```
pod update Firebase
```

You should now have Firebase 3.2.0

Comment: That was the solution.  Has someone mentioned this to the Firebase team?

Answer (score 1):

I think your Podfile should look like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'FirebaseDemo2' do
     pod 'Firebase'
end
```

Make sure to open the Xcodeworkspace and not the Project

Comment: That didn't do it.  I'm using the workspace file too.  I don't understand this.  I've used CocoaPods in the past with no problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you have not installed version 3.2.0? I have the same problem right now, struggling with cocoa pods not fetching the latest version of firebase.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was.  As @Vugario mentioned below (I saw his answer first) `pod update Firebase` will fetch v3.2.0 and it works fine after that.